# Angular.js, how to pass value from one component to any other

Tags: angularjs

Im begginer with Angular.js, so if I dont explain something enought, I will add it to question, just tell me.

I have: `A component.js` `A template.html` `B component.js` `B template.html`.

`A component.js` has `$scope.isActive = true`, and code changes value as needed. This attribute works in template `A template.html`.

Problem is, that I want to use same value, for `B template.html`. I have no idea how to pass it, I have also `B component.js` working with `B template.html`, if this matters somehow.

Right now Im trying to use `$scope.isActive` from `A component.js` in `B template.html`, but it does nothing, I guess it comes `undefined`.

This is how I try to use it in `B template.html`

```
<img src="res/large-loading.gif" ng-if="!isActive">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to move $scope.isActive to a new 'root' component that contains both 'component A' and 'component B'.
Then you can pass / modify its value using input/output bindings in the 'component A' and 'component B' definitions like:

component A definition:

```
angular.module('app').component('componentA', {    
    templateUrl: 'component-A.html',                 
    bindings: {
       isActive: "<", // use to bind property as component input
       isActiveChanged: "&" // use to bind a METHOD that changes the property in the root component controller
    }
});
```

component A template (component-A.html):

```
<img 
   src="res/large-loading.gif" 
   ng-if="!$ctrl.isActive" 
   ng-click="$ctrl.isActiveChanged({isActive: !$ctrl.isActive})"/>
```

component B definition:

```
angular.module('app').component('componentB', {    
    template: 'component-B.html',                 
    bindings: {
       isActive: "<", // use to bind property as component input
       isActiveChanged: "&" // use to bind a METHOD that changes the property in the root component controller
    }
});
```

component B template (component-B.html):

```
<img 
   src="res/large-loading.gif" 
   ng-if="!$ctrl.isActive" 
   ng-click="$ctrl.isActiveChanged({isActive: !$ctrl.isActive})"/>
```

root component definition:

```
angular.module('app').component('root', {    
    templateUrl: 'root-component-view.html', ,                 
    controller: 'RootComponentCtrl'
});
```

root component controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('RootComponentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   // INPUT: This property is shared with both 'component A' and 'component B'
   $scope.isActive = true; 
   // OUTPUT: This method is shared with both 'component A' and 'component B' and can be called from both in order to change the value of $scope.isActive in the RootComponentCtrl
   $scope.isActiveChanged(isActive) {
      $scope.isActive = isActive;
   };
}]);
```

root-component-view.html template:

```
<div>
   <component-a 
      is-active="isActive" 
      is-active-changed="isActiveChanged(isActive)"
   ></component-a>
   <component-b 
      is-active="isActive" 
      is-active-changed="isActiveChanged(isActive)"
   ></component-b>
</div>
```

Notice that binded properties are accessed in the component view/template using the '$ctrl' object like '$ctrl.isActive' as opposed to simply using 'isActive' which refers to the component's $scope.isActive property in the component controller.

To resume:
The shared property is set in the root component controller using:

```
$scope.isActive = true;
```

The shared property can be seen in the root component template using:

```
...>some html text content plus this is {{isActive}}<...
```

The shared property is passed to componentA and componentB in the html that defines them in the root component view using:

```
<component-a 
      is-active="isActive" 
      is-active-changed="isActiveChanged(isActive)"
   ></component-a>
   <component-b 
      is-active="isActive" 
      is-active-changed="isActiveChanged(isActive)"
   ></component-b>
```

The shared property is visible in componentA / componentB templates using:

```
...>some html text content plus this is {{$ctrl.isActive}}<...
```

The shared property is visible in componentA / componentB controllers using:

```
   this.isActive // not $scope.isActive
```

The shared property can be changed from componentA / componentB controllers by calling the method:

```
$ctrl.isActiveChanged({data: data})
```

Which actually will call the method in the root component controller and pass the updated value to the $scope property:

```
$scope.isActiveChanged(data)
```